# win8 enable backspace to navigate back

Tags: windows-8

I am working on a Windows Store app. I want to enable "backspace key to navigate back" feature in my app, just like what the native apps do (Travel, News and etc.) Any idea about how to implement this? Should I have a listener capturing all keyboard inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen for the `KeyUp` event. If you use one of the standard template, the the main `Grid` is a good place to attach the handler.

```
if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Back)
{
    GoBack(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: would this capture all backspace pressing on the page? there might be a textbox on the page and i don't want the page to navigate back if the focus is on the textbox.

Comment: If you press backspace in a `TextBox`, the `KeyUp` handler on the `Grid` will not be called, so it will work as desired

Comment: @user1437038 you are right, you need to add another`KeyUp` handler to the `TextBox` with `e.Handled=true` so that the event does not get to the `Grid`

Comment: that should work! i have also come up with another implementation which works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is my implementation, which works well!

```
if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Back && !e.OriginalSource.GetType().Equals(typeof(TextBox)))
{
    GoBack(sender, e);
}
```